# Trying to find a good word for 'a small discussion' or perhaps 'a focused discussion'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

Almost like the opposite of 'palaver'.  I like the word 'palaver' but it generally (as I understand it) means a needlessly long conversation.  I'm thinking more like a short, or intensely focused conversation.  Ideally not a common word like 'chat', which is so generic as to mean any kind of short talk.

Edit:

I'm pretty flexible on the context, but for the sake of scoping the question, let's say it's between a handful of colleagues with the intent of building understanding or figuring something out.

Comment: Without the context and purpose, I'm afraid we're just going to be flailing around.  A short discussion, between 2 colleagues, resulting in a particular kind of outcome is very different from a short discussion, between 4 strangers, with no conclusion.

Comment: Ok, edited with more context.

Comment: There are about a hundred synonyms for "chat" [here](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/chat).  Pick one.  (I kind of like "parley".)

Comment: You could adapt the American Football term *huddle* to your purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the context, this could be called a ***breakout session***. This term is typically used at academic/industry conferences, and refers to time set aside for smaller groups of people to discuss a narrow focus area related to the main topic of the conference. It's useful for conveying the focused nature of the discussion compared to the relatively broad content of the meeting.

Comment: yeah, I think that's pretty close to the mark

Comment: @Paul - You do have to be careful with this phrase, because you can't schedule a stand-alone "breakout session."  It would have to be a subset of some larger group.  It works great in the context of a conference, or a large class at a university, though.

Answer (score 1):

You want to **check in with** your colleagues [**on** _______ (topic)].  That implies a specific, focused discussion, in which each person speaks only briefly.

I couldn't find the right definition, I'm sorry.

Example: "Let's check in again in a week's time, to see how everyone is doing with their assignments."

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest the word **confab** as in the following scenario:

The team from the PR department did a great job yesterday, holding a **confab** over lunch that produced the outline of our new advertising campaign.

**confab:** *informal*
"An informal private conversation or discussion";

*North American*
"A meeting or conference of members of a particular group."
(Oxford Living Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

Brainstorming, a brainstorm session or "we were all at the round table, each of us bent forward at various angles, as if the closer our faces were to the blueprints the more successful the brainstorming session."

hope this helps!

Comment: Brainstorming works if the small discussion is about creating new ideas/solutions but isn't a good fit for other types of discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's sort of slang but the term  **“coffee klatch”** is a great way to express conversational chat, as in, "the three office workers were engaged in a *coffee klatch*, as their boss watched from behind the cubicle."

I also love to use the word **gabbing**, as in *"the two teenagers were **gabbing** about their boyfriends."*